# Regarding an adding a condition in an xslif block

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the below query , as shown below e  there is an condition on

```
<xsl:if test="./Id='AAA' and ./Role='YYY'">
<xsl:value-of select=" 'true'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Now I want to extend this by putting another condition with respect to this
that it should also allow for id BBB and role ZZZ , please advise how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="(./Id='AAA' and ./Role='YYY') or (./Id='BBB' and ./Role='ZZZ')">
    <xsl:value-of select=" 'true'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had to define more Ids and Roles it would be a bit clunky to define such complex condition. You could also make special variable with allowed combinations, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedUsers">
    <User id="AAA" role="ZZZ" />
    <User id="BBB" role="YYY" />
</xsl:variable>
```

And then just check if it contains record about tested Id and Role.

```
<xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="." />
<xsl:if test="$AllowedUsers/User[@id = $CurrentElement/Id and @role = $CurrentElement/Role]">
    <xsl:value-of select="true" />
</xsl:if>
```

It is just an idea, @Tom was absolutely correct.